# the form clears the array everytime I send it

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a form with 2 selects, when you send the first, the second select charges the values that are called on my oracle bd with a query, then when i send the second select, it generates a table with checkboxes:

```
if(isset($idTActi)){
  $stallTableTarifas=oci_parse($conn, "SELECT TARIFAS.ID, TARIFAS.ID_TIPO_ACTIVIDAD, TARIFAS.TIPO, TIPO_ACTIVIDAD.TEMPS_KM, TARIFAS.PRECIO 
                                       FROM TARIFAS, TIPO_ACTIVIDAD         
                                       WHERE TARIFAS.ID_TIPO_ACTIVIDAD = TIPO_ACTIVIDAD.ID 
                                       AND TARIFAS.ID_TIPO_ACTIVIDAD = $idTActi");
  oci_execute($stallTableTarifas);
  echo "<div class='divPrecios'>";
    echo "<table>";
      echo "<tr class='tabPreciosTitles'>";
        echo "<td>Tipus Tarifa</td>
              <td>Temps/Km</td>
              <td>Preu</td>
              <td><input type='submit' class='carrito' value=''></td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      while (($row=oci_fetch_array($stallTableTarifas,OCI_BOTH))!=false){
        echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>".$row['TIPO']."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row['TEMPS_KM']."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row['PRECIO']."</td>";
          echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value='".$row['ID']."'/></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
      }
    echo "</table>";
  echo "</div>";
}
echo "</form>";
```

The variable $idTActi it's the id that i return from the second select, so when i click on the checkboxes and i send it on the button named class='carrito', that's an sprite that i generate on css, i see on the bottom another table with the information that i selected on the previous table:

```
echo "<div class='divPrecios'>";
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr class='tabPreciosTitles'>";
  echo "<td>Nom Activitat</td>
        <td>Nom Tipus Activitat</td>
        <td>Tipus Tarifa</td>
        <td>Temps/km</td>
        <td>Preu</td>";
echo "</tr>";
foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $item){
  $stallTableCarrito=oci_parse($conn, "SELECT ACTIVIDAD.NOM AS NOM_ACTIVIDAD, TIPO_ACTIVIDAD.NOM AS NOM_TACTIVIDAD, TARIFAS.TIPO, TIPO_ACTIVIDAD.TEMPS_KM, TARIFAS.PRECIO
                                       FROM TARIFAS, ACTIVIDAD, TIPO_ACTIVIDAD
                                       WHERE TARIFAS.ID = $item
                                       AND TARIFAS.ID_TIPO_ACTIVIDAD = TIPO_ACTIVIDAD.ID
                                       AND TIPO_ACTIVIDAD.ID_ACTIVIDAD = ACTIVIDAD.ID");
  oci_execute($stallTableCarrito);

  $array=array(
    0=>array(),
    1=>array(),
    2=>array(),
    3=>array(),
    4=>array()
  );

  while (($row=oci_fetch_array($stallTableCarrito,OCI_BOTH))!=false){
      array_push($array[0],$row['NOM_ACTIVIDAD']);
      array_push($array[1],$row['NOM_TACTIVIDAD']);
      array_push($array[2],$row['TIPO']);
      array_push($array[3],$row['TEMPS_KM']);
      array_push($array[4],$row['PRECIO']);
  }

  for ($x=0;$x<count($array[0]);$x++){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "  <td>".$array[0][$x]."</td>";
    echo "  <td>".$array[1][$x]."</td>";
    echo "  <td>".$array[2][$x]."</td>";
    echo "  <td>".$array[3][$x]."</td>";
    echo "  <td>".$array[4][$x]."</td>";
    echo "  <td><input type='submit' class='carritoElim' value=''></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
  }
}   

echo "</table>";
echo "</div>";
```

Basically that's a shopping form.

**And where is the problem?** When i send the pushed checkboxes with the button class='carrito', the form by default refresh the page and clears my array, what can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first part of code, is your form tag open ? (I guess it is if this one works)

---

In the second part, is your `<input type='submit' class='carritoElim' value=''>` tag in a form ?
Because if it's not, you gonna have a bad time ;-)

---

Maybe in the last form you should generate hidden input with same names as your first form and same values.

If you don't I guess your variable $idTActi won't be set anymore and it won't succeed the first test `if(isset($idTActi))`. That could be why you get a cleared page.

---

If you have a multi step form in the same php page, for this kind of html code :

```
<form method=POST url="myURL">
  <select name="select1">[...]</select>
  <select name="select2">[...]</select>
  <!-- VARIOUS PART : may not be displayed -->
  <div id="checkboxes">
    <input type="hidden" name="boxStep" value="1"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cb1" value="1"/>
    [...]
  </div>
  <!-- END OF VARIOUS PART -->
</form>
```

Then you need php tests in this order :

```
// if post request
if (isset($_POST)) {
    if (isset($_POST['boxStep'])) {
        // behavior when checkboxes values are sent
    } else {
        if (isset($_POST['select2'])) {
            // behavior when second select is filled
            // display "VARIOUS PART"
        } else {
            // behavior when only first select is filled
            // Do not display "VARIOUS PART"
        }
    }
} else {
    // default behavior (no select filled)
    // Do not display "VARIOUS PART"
}
```

Apolo

Comment: Apolo, first thanks for the response, on the second part, the input it's not implemented yet :), only shows the sprite, i generate the code later, mm the second table with the checkboxes doesn't clears, only the variable with the array

Comment: I have difficulties understanding how your code works. You have two select in the same form, and the behavior of the submit action should change depending on the second select content ?

Comment: right, the second select returns an id depending on the selected, and then i do a query with the id returned that prints the first form with the checkboxes, and the last form prints all the info referenced by the options selected on the checkboxes :D

Comment: sorry for answer it too later, but i was left my job when u post the comment, thanksç

Comment: thanks i gonna implement it later, i tell u something when it's all done or maybe has another mistake, thanks :D

Comment: When you think it solve your problem, could you approve my answer please ?